# Expressing a When statement in Elegant Mathematics

Tags: notation

I would like to elegantly describe the sentence below using mathematical notations.

> In the case when distance $z$ between $x$ and $y$ follows a uniform distribution such that $z$ satisfies $[x, y]$ $(0\leq x< y)$, parameter $q$ can be obtained using Equation 1. Otherwise it is as given in Equation 2

$q = (e^-z) x^2 + y^2 $  ---------(1)

$q = \sqrt\frac{1}{2}z$    ---------(2)

How best could this be described?

Note: The parameter $q$ does not represent any unique mathematical expression I know in literature. I have included it to complete a framework for the question

Comment: What is the "i.e" for? Should there be a comma after "[x,y]"? The sentence is incomplete, and you should give some context or meaning of the variables.

Comment: Still incomplete

Comment: I added more exposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [definition by cases](http://timmurphy.org/2011/12/12/math-case-definitions-in-latex/) :

$\begin{equation*}
    q = \begin{cases}
               (e^{-z}) x^2 + y^2              & \text {when...}\\
               \sqrt\frac{1}{2}z             
               & \text{otherwise}
           \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$